# SVG.JS Responsive rect with 100vw and 100vh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I'm trying to maken an offset rectangle that can fit and re-scale according to browser window. I'm pretty new to javascripting and SVG so maybe someone here has a little more knowledge.

Here is a Codepen of the code that I've been trying to figure out.
As you can see, the rectangle doesnt behave the right way. Would be grateful for all the tips I can get.

https://codepen.io/LinusFree/pen/jZNQxg

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var draw = SVG('wrapper').size(100, 100)
var rect = draw.rect(100, 100).move(30, 30).attr({ stroke: '#f06', fill: 'none' })
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {

  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;

}

svg {

  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;

}

rect {

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;

}
```

Comment: it's the `.move(30, 30)` that's messing it up, take that out?

Comment: No, the move 30, 30 makes the rect have an offset from the edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider that your `rect` is moving with 30px on x and y so you have to decrease its size and also use `vh` and `vw` unit. You may also remove white space to avoid having scroll bar:

```js
var draw = SVG('wrapper').size(100, 100)
var rect = draw.rect(100, 100).move(30, 30).attr({
  stroke: '#f06',
  fill: 'none'
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0; /*Don't forget this*/
  font-size:0; /*remove white space*/
}

/*
useless
#wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
*/

svg {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

rect {
  width: calc(100vw - 60px); /* we remove 60px to keep the same offset (30px) on both sides*/
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/2.6.3/svg.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

The above solution seems to work only on chrome so here is another one more supported:

```js
var draw = SVG('wrapper').size(100, 100)
var rect = draw.rect($(window).width() - 60, $(window).height() - 60).move(30, 30).attr({
  stroke: '#f06',
  fill: 'none'
})
$(window).resize(function() {
  $('svg rect').attr('height', $(window).height() - 60);
  $('svg rect').attr('width', $(window).width() - 60);
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;/*Don't forget this*/
  font-size: 0;/*remove white space*/
}


svg {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/2.6.3/svg.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
</div>
```

Comment: @RobertLongson hmm true ... i guess the width/height i used is not supported with SVG element. Will update then

Comment: @RobertLongson updated with another solution but was obliged to dynamically change the height/width on window resize ... didn't find a static CSS way